# Uploading and downloading small files to a cloud drive in-game? (Unity3D)

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, download, upload

I need any player's client to be able to upload and download files (they are text files that have replay data. I'm making a racing game and want players to be able to send and download replays.) while in-game. I'm trying to use Dropbox but I'm having problems. I'm open to other file hosting services but I don't really know how to send and get data from them. I keep making little changes here and there and they all give me different errors. Is there anything I'm doing blatantly wrong here? I'm expecting the main problem to be in the dropbox URL I'm using. Here's what my code looks like:

```
    private void DownloadReplay()
{
    string l_playerID = PlayFabManager.load_PlayfabId;
    string l_levelID = PlayFabManager.load_levelID;
    
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, $"{l_playerID}{l_levelID}.replay");
        string url = ("https://www.dropbox.com/s/f786vep0z9yd11s/"+ $"{l_playerID}{l_levelID}");
        wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xx", "xx");
        wc.DownloadFile((new System.Uri(url)), path);
    }
}

private void UploadReplay()
{
    string s_playerID = PlayFabManager.load_PlayfabId;
    string s_levelID = PlayFabManager.load_levelID;

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, $"{s_playerID}{s_levelID}.replay");
        string url = Path.Combine("https://www.dropbox.com/s/f786vep0z9yd11s/" + $"{s_playerID}{s_levelID}");
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xx", "xx");
        client.UploadFile(url, path);
    }
}
```

Right now this one gives me an error 404, even though the file matching the string is in my dropbox.

Comment: That's not how the [Dropbox Web API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation) works ;) I'd recommend using their [Dropbox .NET SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet)

Comment: I ended up going with a up/down file system from the asset store, but thanks for the info!!!